# sample(.) versus calculated probabilities

Tags: r

Where is my mistake in the following code/reasoning.

If I have `n` items and I want to count the number of combinations (i.e. order does not matter) of draws of size `k` *with* replacement I can use the binomial coefficient:

```
choose(n + k - 1, k)
```

When I want to count the number of possibilities where element `i` is not part of the draw I would thus use

```
choose(n + k - 1 - 1, k)
```

(Basically I have one option less to draw from).

E.g. with `n=3, k= 3` I have the following `10` (`choose(3 + 3 - 1, 3)`) draws:

```
# AAA, AAB, ABB, BBB, BBC, BCC, CCC, CCA, CAA, ABC
```

The ones where element `'A'` (say) does not appear, are the following `4` (`choose(3 + 3 - 1 - 1, 3)`):

```
# BBB, BBC, BCC, CCC
```

So far so good. I can thus calculate the probability that I have a draw with `n = k` where element `i` is not appearing:

```
freeFromCounts <- function(n) choose(2 * n - 2, n)
totalCounts    <- function(n) choose(2 * n - 1, n)
ratio          <- function(n) freeFromCounts(n) / totalCounts(n) ## (n - 1) / (2 * n - 1)
```

So here is my problem if I simulate the draws (with `sample(.)`) and repeat that `n.rep` times, I would expect to see about `n.rep * ratio(n)` draws where element `1` (say) is not present. This is, however, not the case. Where is my mistake?

```
sim <- function(n, n.rep = 10000, x0 = 1) {
    sum(replicate(n.rep, {
       s <- sample(n, n, TRUE)
       all(s != x0)
    })) / n.rep
}

set.seed(12)
sim(10, 1e6)  # [1] 0.348278
ratio(10)     # [1] 0.4736842
```

Comment: I have been thinking about this for sometime.
`sim2 <- function(n, n.rep = 10000, x0 = 1) {
  sum(replicate(n.rep, {
    s <- sample(rep(1:n,n), n,F)
    all(s != x0)
  })) / n.rep
}


set.seed(12)
sim2(10, 1e6)  # [1] 0.33136`

Even though this function should give similar results as yours it gives out lesser probability. I'm not sure if it is because of the way the sampling works

Comment: did you find any answers to your question

Comment: No answers yet. `sim2` and `sim` are practically equivalent. But 47% vs 35% that seems too much for me...

Comment: And for what it's worth, bigger `n.rep` does not help either: `sim(10, 1e7) # [1] 0.3487594`

Comment: Yes that's what my point was, `sim2` though equivalent to `sim`, has a consistently lesser probability of ~33% compared to ~35% from `sim` and bigger n.rep doesn't help. `sim` & `sim2` seem to converge as n is increased. For large n ratio tends to 0.5, but sim & sim2 seem to tend to 0.37 (as far as I could compute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague found the solution. `sample` samples not *unordered* but **ordered**, i.e. it make a difference between `[1, 2, 3]` and `[3, 2, 1]`. With this knowledge the figures are the same: `9 ^ 10 / 10 ^ 10 = 0.3486784`.

So to do the simulation for the original problem, you have to come up with a variant of `sample` which does **unordered sampling**. Idea is following the famous derivation of the formula for unordered sampling with replacement (cf. e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html)

```
sampleUnordered <- function(n, k) {
  aS <- rep(0, n + k -1)
  aS[!seq_along(aS) %in% sample(n + k - 1, k)] <- seq.int(n-1)
  rl <- rle(aS)
  zeros <- which(rl$values == 0)
  good <- rl$lengths[zeros]
  nr <- c(rl$values, n)[zeros + 1]
  rep(nr, good)
}

sim <- function(n, n.rep = 10000, x0 = 1) {
    sum(replicate(n.rep, {
       s <- sampleUnordered(n, n)
       all(s != x0)
    })) / n.rep
}

set.seed(12)
sim(10, 1e6) # [1] 0.473234
```